# GPUImage group filters

Tags: ios, image, gpuimage

I am trying to implement brightness,contrast and exposure filters in a single view same as you see in iPhoto app. I have tried to put up group filter for doing the same. But it shows up a white screen instead of modified picture. Here is the code I applied.

```
 GPUImageFilterGroup *groupFilter = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc]init];
    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc]init];
    [brightnessFilter setBrightness:brightnessValue];
    GPUImageContrastFilter *contrastFilter = [[GPUImageContrastFilter alloc]init];
    [contrastFilter setContrast:contrastValue];
    GPUImageExposureFilter *exposureFilter =[[GPUImageExposureFilter alloc]init];
    [exposureFilter setExposure:exposureValue];
    [groupFilter addFilter:brightnessFilter];
    [groupFilter addFilter:contrastFilter];
    [groupFilter addFilter:exposureFilter];
     GPUImagePicture *stillImage= [[GPUImagePicture alloc]initWithImage:self.imageToModify];
    [stillImage addTarget:groupFilter];


    [stillImage processImage];

    previewPicture.image = [groupFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:self.imageToModify.imageOrientation];
```

I even tried to put each individually but still it shows up white image. Is the above code I am using correct?
I have also tried using `GPUImageFilterPipeline` instead of `GPUImageFilterGroup` but still having the same issue. 
For the record, the image is a still image and not live feed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have missed some code statement for doing it which is as below.

```
   [brightnessFilter addTarget: contrastFilter];
   [contrastFilter addTarget: exposureFilter];

  [(GPUImageFilterGroup *) groupFilter setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject: brightnessFilter]];
  [(GPUImageFilterGroup *) groupFilter setTerminalFilter:exposureFilter];
```

Thanks

Comment: [brightnessFilter addTarget: contrastFilter];
   [contrastFilter addTarget: exposureFilter];
Are you sure about these two?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a full code to apply Brightness, Contrast and Saturation to video**

**i get the reference code from** [this link](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2014/06/object-overlay-on-video/) and i make change in that..

** **in this code we use GPUImage Frameworks**

**1). in .h file**

```
#import "GPUImage.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    GPUImageMovie *movieFile;
    GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter;
    GPUImageUIElement *uiElementInput;
}
```

**2). in .m file**

```
- (void)editVideo
{
    NSURL *sampleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Sample Video" withExtension:@"m4v"];

    movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];
    movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
    movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = YES;

    GPUImageFilterGroup *groupFilter = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc]init]; //1

    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init]; //2
    GPUImageContrastFilter *contrastFilter = [[GPUImageContrastFilter alloc] init]; //3
    GPUImageSaturationFilter *saturationFilter = [[GPUImageSaturationFilter alloc] init]; //4

    [(GPUImageBrightnessFilter*)brightnessFilter setBrightness:0.10]; // change value between -1.00 to 1.00
    [(GPUImageContrastFilter*)contrastFilter setContrast:1.48];     // change value between 0.00 to 4.00
    [(GPUImageSaturationFilter*)saturationFilter setSaturation:2.00];   //change value between 0.00 to 2.00

    GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init]; //5
    blendFilter.mix = 0.0;

                                                            /* ************************************************** */

    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-20)];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    uiElementInput = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:contentView];
    [brightnessFilter addTarget:contrastFilter];
    [contrastFilter addTarget:saturationFilter];
    [saturationFilter addTarget:blendFilter];
    [uiElementInput addTarget:blendFilter];

    [(GPUImageFilterGroup *) groupFilter setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject: brightnessFilter]];
    [(GPUImageFilterGroup *) groupFilter setTerminalFilter:blendFilter];

    [movieFile addTarget:brightnessFilter];
    [movieFile addTarget:contrastFilter];
    [movieFile addTarget:saturationFilter];

    // Only rotate the video for display, leave orientation the same for recording
    GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)vwVideo;
    [brightnessFilter addTarget:filterView];
    [contrastFilter addTarget:filterView];
    [saturationFilter addTarget:filterView];
    [blendFilter addTarget:filterView];

    [brightnessFilter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput * filter, CMTime frameTime){
        if (frameTime.value/frameTime.timescale == 2) {
            [contentView viewWithTag:1].hidden = NO;
        }
        [uiElementInput update];
    }];

    [contrastFilter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput * filter, CMTime frameTime){
        if (frameTime.value/frameTime.timescale == 2) {
            [contentView viewWithTag:1].hidden = NO;
        }
        [uiElementInput update];
    }];

    [saturationFilter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput * filter, CMTime frameTime){
        if (frameTime.value/frameTime.timescale == 2) {
            [contentView viewWithTag:1].hidden = NO;
        }
        [uiElementInput update];
    }];

    //In addition to displaying to the screen, write out a processed version of the movie to disk
    NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
    unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie

    movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie] size:CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0)];
    [brightnessFilter addTarget:movieWriter];
    [contrastFilter addTarget:movieWriter];
    [blendFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

    // Configure this for video from the movie file, where we want to preserve all video frames and audio samples
    movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
    movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
    [movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

    [movieWriter startRecording];
    [movieFile startProcessing];

    [movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathToMovie, nil, nil, nil);
    }];
}
```

***Note :- Please run that demo example in device not in simulator for perfect result.**

**After process done you will get effected video in your device and for different effect you can change the value at setBrightness ,  setContrast and setSaturation (see in code)**